# i get a null reference exception after trying to print data from my database in android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql

Thank for reading my inquiry. I know this question has been asked before but I didn't find the answer I was looking for in the other responses. I hope I will ask the right question.

this code is for my DataBase Handler. 
It houses all the methods that pertain to it, such as creating the table, adding and deleting entries and printing the database in my app.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class EmailDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "loginEntries.db";
public static final String TABLE_LOGINENTRIES = "loginEntries";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NICKNAME = "nickname";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS = "emailAddress";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String COLUMN_LASTNAME = "lastName";
public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "firstName";


public EmailDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NICKNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_LASTNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT " +
            /*COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " INTEGER " +*/
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
    String queryTwo = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES +
            " (" + COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS + ", " +
            COLUMN_NICKNAME + ", " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + ", " +
            COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + ", " +
            COLUMN_LASTNAME + " " +
           /* COLUMN_PHONENUMBER +*/ ")" + " VALUES " + " (\'email address\', \'nickname\', \'password\', \' First Name\', \'Last Name \');";
    db.execSQL(queryTwo);
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);


}

public String logInCheck(String loginEmailEntry){
    //used to find email and password in the database to compare to entered entries to confirm user

    String passwordHolder;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS  + "=\"" + loginEmailEntry + "\"";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    passwordHolder = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD));
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return passwordHolder;


}

public boolean signUpEmailCheck(String emailEntry){
//checks if a new email entry already exists in the database
    Integer holder;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS  + "=\"" + emailEntry + "\"";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    holder = c.getColumnCount();
    if (holder > 0) {
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return false;
    }
}

//add new row to Database

public void addEntry(LoginEntries entry){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS,entry.get_emailAddress());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,entry.get_password());
    values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,entry.get_firstName());
    values.put(COLUMN_LASTNAME,entry.get_lastName());
    values.put(COLUMN_NICKNAME,entry.get_nickname());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGINENTRIES, null, values);
    db.close();
}


//delete items from database

public void deleteEmailEntry(String emailEntry){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS + "=\"" +
            emailEntry + "\";");
}
public void deleteNickname(String nicknameEntry){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NICKNAME + "=\"" +
            nicknameEntry + "\";");
}
public void deletePasswordEntry(String passwordEntry){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "=\"" +
            passwordEntry + "\";");
}
public void deleteLastNameEntry(String lastNameEntry){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_LASTNAME + "=\"" +
            lastNameEntry + "\";");
}
public void deleteFirstNameEntry(String FirstNameEntry){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + "=\"" +
            FirstNameEntry + "\";");
}
//Print database as a string
public String emailDatabaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

    //cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS)) !=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS));
            dbString += "\n";
        }c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
}
public String passwordDatabaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

    //cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD)) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
}
public String firstNameDatabaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

    //cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME)) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
}
public String lastNameDatabaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

    //cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LASTNAME)) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LASTNAME));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
}

public String nicknameDatabaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGINENTRIES + " WHERE 1";

    //cursor point to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NICKNAME)) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NICKNAME));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    c.close();
    return dbString;
}
}
```

This class is my sign up class, where I input new data into my database. Most of the if statements dictate the user if they are entering data incorrectly.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUpMainClass extends AppCompatActivity{

EditText newEmailAddressInput;
EditText newPasswordInput;
EditText confirmNewPasswordInput;
TextView newFirstNameInput;
TextView newLastNameInput;
TextView newNickname;
TextView displayNickname;
TextView displayEmail;
TextView displayPassword;
TextView displayFirstName;
TextView displayLastName;
// EditText newPhoneNumberInput;
EmailDBHandler dbHandler;
//SignUpWelcomeScreen inputEntry;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup_main);

    newEmailAddressInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newEmailAddressInput);
    newPasswordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPasswordInput);
    confirmNewPasswordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmNewPasswordInput);
    newFirstNameInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newFirstNameInput);
    newLastNameInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newLastNameInput);
    newNickname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newNickname);
    dbHandler = new EmailDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    Bundle nameData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(nameData == null){
        return;
    }


    String  newFirstNameMessage =nameData.getString("newFirstNameMessage");
    String  newLastNameMessage =nameData.getString("newLastNameMessage");
    String  newNicknameMessage =nameData.getString("newNicknameMessage");


    newFirstNameInput.setText(newFirstNameMessage);
    newLastNameInput.setText(newLastNameMessage);
    newNickname.setText(newNicknameMessage);
}

public void registerAccount(View view) {
    LoginEntries emailEntry = new LoginEntries(newEmailAddressInput.getText().toString(), "", "", "", "");
    String isTempEmail = newEmailAddressInput.getText().toString();
    LoginEntries passwordEntry = new LoginEntries("", newPasswordInput.getText().toString(), "", "","");
    String isTempPass = newPasswordInput.getText().toString();
    String confirmPasswordHolder = confirmNewPasswordInput.getText().toString();
    LoginEntries newFirstNameEntry = new LoginEntries("", "", newFirstNameInput.getText().toString(), "", "");
    LoginEntries newLastNameEntry = new LoginEntries("", "", "", newLastNameInput.getText().toString(),"");
    LoginEntries newNicknameEntry = new LoginEntries("", "", "", "", newNickname.getText().toString());



    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempEmail) && TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempEmail) && TextUtils.isEmpty(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } /*Temporary while app is offline, when app will be operational, different prompt will search web to verify email address*/
    else if (!isTempEmail.endsWith("@gmail.com") && !isTempEmail.endsWith("@yahoo.com") && !isTempEmail.endsWith("@aol.com") && !isTempEmail.endsWith("@hotmail.com")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not a valid email address, trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (!dbHandler.signUpEmailCheck(isTempEmail)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email used, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newEmailAddressInput.setText("");
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else if (!confirmPasswordHolder.equals(isTempPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        newPasswordInput.setText("");
        confirmNewPasswordInput.setText("");
    } else{


        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondarySignUpClass.class);

        String firstName = newFirstNameInput.getText().toString();
        String lastName = newLastNameInput.getText().toString();
        String nickname = newNickname.getText().toString();

        i.putExtra("newFirstNameMessage",firstName);
        i.putExtra("newLastNameMessage",lastName);
        i.putExtra("newNicknameMessage", nickname);

        startActivity(i);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dbHandler.addEntry(emailEntry);// adds email to database
        dbHandler.addEntry(passwordEntry);//adds password to database
        dbHandler.addEntry(newFirstNameEntry);//adds First Name to database
        dbHandler.addEntry(newLastNameEntry);//adds Last name to database
        dbHandler.addEntry(newNicknameEntry);//adds Nickname to Database
        printDatabase();



    }
}


public void printDatabase(){
    String dbEmailString = dbHandler.emailDatabaseToString();
    String dbPasswordString = dbHandler.passwordDatabaseToString();
    String dbFirstNameString = dbHandler.firstNameDatabaseToString();
    String dbLastNameString = dbHandler.lastNameDatabaseToString();
    String dbNicknameString= dbHandler.nicknameDatabaseToString();
    displayEmail.setText(dbEmailString);
    displayPassword.setText(dbPasswordString);
    displayFirstName.setText(dbFirstNameString);
    displayLastName.setText(dbLastNameString);
    displayNickname.setText(dbNicknameString);


    }
}
```

My input process is simple. It is meant to be a login in for a generic app, most likely a social app. User presses a sign up button, it takes him to the xml that the above class is attached to. The user puts in the data(first name, last name, email, password, nickname) and presses the Register button which is the associated with the Register account method. The information is then supposed to be entered into the database, from which I can later extract it. But it doesn't. 
This is the error message I receive in my logcat when I try to extract data from the database. I assume that I missed something Small that plays a big part but I'm not sure what it is.

```
Process: com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial, PID: 15139
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(App    CompatViewInflater.java:275)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.SignUpMainClass.printDatabase(SignUpMainClass.java:165)
at com.example.vitaliy_2.emailpassworddatabasetrial.SignUpMainClass.registerAccount(SignUpMainClass.java:135)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)at com.android.internal.os.Zygote

Init.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Thank you for getting this far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference

**`TextView object is null`** .

At first you need to set all **TextView** `id`  after **setContentView(R.layout.signup_main);**

```
displayNickname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Your_Id);
displayEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.You_id);
.......// Call Rest of Textview //.............
```

Comment: I have this done in another activity. 


TextView displayEmail;

    EmailDBHandler dbHandler;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp_display_email);

        displayEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayEmail);
        String dbEmailString = dbHandler.emailDatabaseToString();
        displayEmail.setText(dbEmailString);

    }

Comment: I have a separate activity to view each column of the database as a temporary display

Comment: My issue lies more in the fact that the code doesn't seem to save in the database.

Comment: I apologize for not taking your advice at first, but it wasn't what I was looking for. I used it and it worked. Now I just have to figure out how to print the database on the other activities.

Comment: @VitaliyDvorkin okay okay .No problem .Move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

Your *display* TextView objects don"t seem to have been initialized anywhere :

```
TextView displayNickname;
TextView displayEmail;
TextView displayPassword;
TextView displayFirstName;
TextView displayLastName;
```

Comment: I must have forgotten to remove this code. I am printing the database form other activites so i can test multiple entries without crowding the screen

Comment: After going through a couple of hair ripping hours I decided to try to add the displays to the same activity to try to make it easier to debug. IT worked, though with errors, something I must have missed. But then the question arises, why can't the other activities where I declared and initiated the displays, and called the database object to print the database, work?